# Analytic Number Theory Exercise - The Stability Theorem

Tags: number-theory, convolution

This exercise is in the book by P.T. Bateman and H.G. Diamond which i'm not sure whether i perceived it correctly about the integrator involving in the convolution and integral, I was wondering if $$\sum_{n\le x} (T1*\mu)(n)=\int_{1-}^x dF*dG$$ Where $\displaystyle F(x)=\sum_{n\le x} T1(n),G(x)=\sum_{n\le x} \mu(n)$ is true. Note that  $T1(n)=n$ and the eminent Mobius function $\mu(n)$.

The exercise wants the readers to prove that $$\sum_{n\le x}(T1*\mu)(n)=\dfrac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)}+O(x\log x)$$
And I want some hint to this problem because I'm not sure what I've stated above is true or not and even though it's true I have no idea to choose the bound for $F,G$ so that $\zeta(2)$ will stand out using Stability Theorem described in the chapter of the exercise.

I beg on the hint (or at least the clarification on the above) to the bound of maybe either $F,G$ . What gives me the confusions is that $G(x)=O(x)$ trivially

However, I don't think this one can have very sharp bound, and therefore, give not so big pace since even Riemann Hypothesis is true the bound should be $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$, and, I expect that it should be done with the term of $F(x)$.

---

Edited: Here I add the Stability Theorem that states in the chapter that they suggest readers to use the theorem

***Theorem*** (Stability) Let $F,G\in$ the function class $\nu$ and satisfy for all $x\ge 1$ $F(x)=x^sP(\log x)+O(x^\theta\log^K x)$ and $G(x)=O(x^\tau\log^H x)$, where $s\in\mathbb{C}$; $P$ is a polynomial of degree $m$; $K,H\ge 0$;$0\le\tau<\Re(s)$ and $0\le\theta\le \Re(s)$. Then $$\int_{1-}^x dF*dG=x^sP^*(\log x)+R(x)$$ where $\displaystyle P^*(u)=\sum_{l=0}^m\dfrac{1}{l!}P^{(l)}(u)\int_{1-}^\infty (-\log t)^lt^{-s}dG(t)$, in which, $\deg(P)\le m$ and $$R(x) = \cases{O(x^\theta\log^K x) & , $\theta > \tau$ \cr\cr O(x^\theta(\log x)^{H+\max(m,K+1)}) & , $\theta = \tau$ \cr\cr O(x^\tau(\log x)^{H+m}) &  , $\theta<\tau$} $$

Comment: I have no idea what Bateman and Diamond call the "stability theorem", it might be helpful if you add that to your question. Whether your first displayed equation holds depends on the meaning of $\ast$ in $dF \ast dG$. It likely has the meaning making it hold. But I'm not sure it will help. The point is that you know $F(y)$ pretty well, after all it's just $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\lfloor y\rfloor} k\,,$$ which has a popular closed form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my post by adding the theorem, by the way could you please give me that popular closed form?

Comment: The closed form is $\frac{1}{2}\lfloor y\rfloor (\lfloor y\rfloor + 1)$. Thus you have $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \leqslant x} \mu(k) \biggl( \frac{x^2}{k^2} + O\biggl(\frac{x}{k}\biggr)\biggr)$$ overall, from which one easily gets the stated asymptotics. With $F(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x)$ and $G(x) = O(x)$ [by the PNT, $G(x) = o(x)$, but that doesn't give anything more than $O(x)$ here — at least not without much more and very careful work], the result can also be read off the stability theorem directly.

Comment: Sorry but what is $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k\le x}\mu(k)\left(\dfrac{x^2}{k^2}+O\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)\right)$ do you mean something like $\displaystyle \sum_{k\le x} T1\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)\mu(x)$? and is it correct that $$\sum_{n\le x} (T1*\mu)(n)=\int_{1-}^x dF*dG$$. By the way, thank you so much.

Comment: $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} (T1 \ast \mu)(n) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \leqslant x} \mu(k)\biggl(\frac{x^2}{k^2} + O\biggl(\frac{x}{k}\biggr)\biggr)\,.$$ And going by the statement of the theorem you included, the $\ast$ in $dF \ast dG$ has the right meaningfor this sum to be expressible as $\int_{1^-}^x dF \ast dG$.